# How to integrate an on-premises Webapi service and WCF Service with our asp.net application in Azure?

Tags: asp.net, json, xml, azure, webhooks

We have on-premises webApi, WCF, Web Services.  We would like to integrate these on-premises service with Azure.  Any Suggestions?

Comment: Yes: Just do it. But seriously, this question lacks context. What use cases are we talking about, what level of integration?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Relay :

Azure Relay addresses the technical challenge of communication between on-premise service and the external application which does not reside on the same premise or firewall. It allows on-premise service to expose a public endpoint.

[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-faq

HTTP relay

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/receiving-and-handling-http-requests-anywhere-with-the-azure-relay/

Expose an on-premises WCF service to a web application in the cloud by using Azure Relay
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/service-bus-dotnet-hybrid-app-using-service-bus-relay

Comment: Hello Anass Kartit, Thanks for your inputs, I got it for WCF service, but we have WebAPI's also, that how to integrate, if you can point to some article.  These webapi's are developed with Asp.net core.

Comment: I added an example, same technology solves the problem.